# Eclipse RCP failed to Launch product in MAC Big Sur

Tags: macos, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle, tycho

I am getting below stack strace when trying to launch MY RCP application[i.e. based on neon-2] on **MAC machine big sur 11.5.1** ,

```
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Control.java:2176)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:174)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.updateTabHeight(CTabFolder.java:3778)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.runUpdate(CTabFolder.java:3814)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabItem.getBounds(CTabItem.java:149)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onPaint(CTabFolder.java:2049)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:339)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1501)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1524)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1509)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Control.java:1275)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Widget.java:765)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5711)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Display.java:5084)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5465)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(NSApplication.java:94)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3700)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148
```

---

Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: Eclipse Neon is now 5 years and 15 releases old. Older releases of Eclipse have problems running on macOS 11, you need to move to the current release 2021-06 (soon to be 2021-09)